# IBM Watson Conversation doesn´t show the welcome messange in facebook messenger

Tags: ibm-watson, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I integrated the IBM Watson Conversation in the facebook messenger, but it doesn´t show the welcome message (First node of the conversation). 
What can I do to resolve this issue?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Does it show any message?

If it is only the welcome message that is missing, then this will be because the welcome message is only returned at the start of the dialog when no text is provided as input.

If you provide text at the start then the welcome node is bypassed and a match is sought against each of the top level nodes in turn.

Answer (score 0):

If you integrate to messenger then the "Welcome" node doesn't activating instead you can use "conversation_start".

If you have more implementation then you can just add a conversation_start node and from there just jump to the welcome node.